# Regex to extract Asterisk queue statistics

Tags: regex, perl, asterisk

I'm trying to construct some regex to extract stats on queue statuses in Asterisk. I'm relatively new to regex so am quite far off a solution. I have the following output to parse:

```
Parsing /etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf
0009*007 has 2 calls (max unlimited) in 'ringall' strategy (0s holdtime), W:0, C:0, A:7, SL:0.0% within 0s
   Members: 
      0009*001 (Local/0009*001@queue/nj) (In use) has taken no calls yet
   Callers: 
      1. SIP/chan5-000a29f2 (wait: 0:08, prio: 0)
      2. SIP/0139*741-000a29f7 (wait: 0:03, prio: 0)
```

The real output will have info for multiple queues, so it will repeat from the second line. The first line is only displayed once.

I need to end up with the queue ID (in this example 0009*007) and a list of calls with their respective wait time.

So far I have used the following regex to match the queue number:

```
\b^[0-9]{4}\*[0-9]{3}\b
```

But this doesn't work. Not sure how to match the call with the wait time.
Ideally I would like output like this:

```
0009*007,1,0:08
0009*007,2,0:03
```

I will be writing the final script in Perl most likely.

Comment: As a general note, you cannot do this in one regex, because a) matches cannot overlap and b) (except for in .NET) you cannot get an arbitrary number of captures (that would be the wait times) out of a single regex.

Comment: Did you search asterisk tools ? Maybe something exists to display stats in a more _grepable_ way ?!

Comment: I have to agree with Sputnick: This sounds like a solved problem.  I'm betting somewhere out there are tools that handle these log files already.

Comment: I did some more digging and I have to agree, it seems there is a wholly different (read: better) way of doing this. Asterisk spits out queue events into /var/log/asterisk/queue_log, and can also be configured to output to MySQL. I figure I can analyse that data in real time and generate the stats I need. Thanks to all for their contributions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple state machine solution.  The regexes may need to change depending on what kind of variation you expect in the log file.

```
use Modern::Perl;

my $current_queue;
my $in_callers = 0;
while (<DATA>)
{
    if (!defined $current_queue)
    {
         /(\d{4}\*\d{3})/ and $current_queue = $1; 
    }
    elsif (!$in_callers)
    {
        /Callers:/ and $in_callers++;
    }
    elsif (/^\s*(\d+)\..*wait:\s+(\d+:\d+),\s+prio:\s+(\d+)/)
    {
        say "$current_queue,$1,$2,$3";
    }
    else
    {
        #end of this queue; reset.
        undef $current_queue; $in_callers = 0; 
    }
}

__DATA__
Parsing /etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf
0009*007 has 2 calls (max unlimited) in 'ringall' strategy
   Members: 
      0009*001 (Local/0009*001@queue/nj) (In use) has taken no calls yet
   Callers: 
      1. SIP/chan5-000a29f2 (wait: 0:08, prio: 0)
      2. SIP/0139*741-000a29f7 (wait: 0:03, prio: 0)
```

Comment: I commented above, it seems there's a better way of doing this, but this is useful info on regex and will serve me elsewhere. Thanks very much for your input.

Answer (score 2):

As m.buettner indicated, you won't be able to do this with one regex.  You can rely on your knowledge of the repeating nature of the data to generate a hash with the data you need, however, and then print the hash at the end:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %queues;
my $current_queue;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  if (m/^(\d+\*\d+)/) {
    $current_queue = $1;
  }
  elsif (m/^\s+(\d)\..+?\(wait:\s+([\d\:]+),/) {
    $queues{$current_queue}{$1} = $2;
  }
}

foreach my $queue (sort keys %queues) {
  foreach my $caller (sort keys %{ $queues{$queue} }) {
    print join (',', $queue, $caller, $queues{$queue}{$caller}) . "\n";
  }
}

exit;

__DATA__
Parsing /etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf
0009*007 has 2 calls (max unlimited) in 'ringall' strategy (0s holdtime), W:0, C:0, A:7, SL:0.0% within 0s
   Members:
      0009*001 (Local/0009*001@queue/nj) (In use) has taken no calls yet
   Callers:
      1. SIP/chan5-000a29f2 (wait: 0:08, prio: 0)
      2. SIP/0139*741-000a29f7 (wait: 0:03, prio: 0)
```